# Resize left div before right div moves to bottom

Tags: html, css

I have two divs aligned horizontally (`display` is set to `inline-block`). When I resize my browser, I want the left div to resize before the right div moves beneath it.

I've tried setting the `width`, `min-width` and `max-width`, as well as using `media queries`. Nothing seemed to work.

[Here's a picture of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cPSW.png)

```
<div class="left">
    COTENT
</div>
<div class="right">
    CONTENT
</div>
```

```
body {
    margin: 66px auto 24px auto;
    max-width: 900px;
    background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.4);
}

.left {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 594px;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin-right: 6px;
}


.right {
    width: 290px;
    min-width: 290px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way:

```
.left {
    width: calc(100% - 290px);
}
```

And to avoid jumping your right div to the next line, wrap it into div (.container) with flex style into:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

Here's code: https://jsfiddle.net/8utdg4qb/